# how to read XML file and convert it to base64 in soapUI?

Tags: xml, base64, soapui

I'm new in soapUI - I don't use the pro version- and I have an XML file in my laptop, which i want to read it and convert it to base64 and transfer the result to next request, how can i do it?

Comment: You mean as attachment? Because, you can't send the base64 string as request? or is it something different ?

Comment: I write a script which read an XML file and encoded it to Base64 then store the result in another file, i need the value of that file in another request tag, how can i add it?

Comment: Can you please show with a screen shot? how & where you need that?

Answer (score 0):

In a Groovy script, put this code to encode a string readed from a file

```
return new File('/path/from/file').bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
```

Then you can transfer it to another step or get the data from your groovyScript with :

```
def result = context.expand( '${Groovy Script Name#result}' )
```